# Web based solution for large point clouds

Tags: open-source, web-apps, database, 3d, gis

I am looking for a software that would be able to store huge point clouds generated from LIDAR and stereo camera scans of terrain and urban areas (with buildings etc.). I need to visualize the data and possibly also edit it. Everything should be doable via web browser.

I found map servers like [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/) and [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) but since they are rather complex I did not investigate these in depth yet. I also do not know if they can store elevation at all and thus if they are suited for point clouds (they seem to be rather for 2D maps).

According to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57031/huge-point-cloud-laser-data-in-postgis-storing-and-processing-it) point clouds should be possible to store the point cloud in a custom PostGIS database. There also is a [PostgreSQL extension](https://github.com/pgpointcloud/pointcloud) for storing point clouds. [This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77427/viewing-lidar-data-from-web-browser) led me to the [Potree](http://potree.org/) web based point cloud viewer. All these pieces together may form the software in question except the visual editor part.

I prefer open source software.

I am afraid such a complex piece of software with all the features I need may not exist in a single package yet. If anyone could at least confirm this assumption, that would be nice so that I do not need to waste time on further research...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that either MapServer or GeoServer will be able to handle large point cloud datasets, though they can both use PostgreSQL/PostGIS as a data source. If you want some open source software to provide a web service (this is what software like MapServer or GeoServer do) then your only choice as far as I know is [Rasdaman](http://www.rasdaman.org)/[Petascope](http://www.rasdaman.org/wiki/PetascopeUserGuide); where Rasdaman is the data manager and Petascope provides the data service (WCS/WCPS/WMS/WPS).

You can trial Rasdaman (and indeed MapServer and GeoServer) on the [OSGeo-Live distribution.](https://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html)

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasdaman

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what software they use ... but http://cyark.org might be interesting to you ... it lets one view 3D scans of heritage sites as point clouds with millions of points in the web browser.